# Can't open database using SQLite on an UWP written in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, uwp

I am making an UWP in which I need to access a database. To do so I first downloaded and installed the SQL Universal Windows Platform from this link:

https://sqlite.org/download.html

After this was done I added it as a reference and included it in my code with:

```
#include <sqlite3.h> //Not sure if I need to make any other changes for this to work
```

To troubleshoot I have just a button and a textbox. This is the code that it's been run when the button is clicked:

```
    int rc;
    sqlite3 *testDB;

    if (SQLITE_OK == (rc = sqlite3_open("signers.db", &testDB))) { 
        Message->Text = "It worked!";
    }
    else {
        Message->Text = "Can't open Database";
    }
```

signers.db it's a database that I created using SQLite so I could have some data to read from my program. Everytime I run the program the text "Can't open Database" appears. I've tried every solution that I see online but none seem to work for me thus I think that I overseeing something. I am fairly new at UWP and also at using databases.

If you need any additional information feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Where is the database file  located?

Comment: It's on the main folder of the project.

Comment: I changed it now so it's on a subfolder of the main folder called "database" and I changed the first argument of the "sqlite3_open()" function to "ms-appx:///dataBase/signers.db" which I know I have privileges but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the database in your package folder, then it is read-only. You need to use [`sqlite3_open_v2`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) and pass the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` flag.

If you want to open the database for read / write then you need to copy it to your local folder first.

(Also make sure you actually have the database set to deploy; in the Properties window make sure it is set to `Content` and that it will be copied to the output directory).

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

you have some limitations to the location where the db file you want to open is located. sqlite itself should work. Try opening a db in a folder specified in the article.

Could also be just a corrupted db file. Did you try to create an empty one?

Comment: I created a new db file just in case and I made a new folder called dataBase in which I know I can access. I am sure of this because I created another app that could load videos this way. The line in which I read the dB file has been changed to this but it still doesn't seem to open it correctly.

if (SQLITE_OK == (rc = sqlite3_open("ms-appx:///dataBase/signers.db", &testDB))) {
    Message->Text = "It worked!";
   }